# Can't open Windows 8 after installing ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

Yesterday, I tried ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I liked it, so I installed it in my computer with Windows 8.
I managed to create a disk partition in Windows and I named it **U:\UBUNTU**. Then I installed Ubuntu inside this partition, but now, when I try to enter in my Windows 8, it gives me an error message:

> error: Secure Boot forbids loading module from (hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub/ntfs.mod.
>
> error: no such device: 2402319002316706
>
> error: unknow command 'drivemap'.
>
> error: invalid EFI file path.
>
> Press any key to continue...

What can I do? Please I need urgent help, I need to access to Windows 8 and I don't want to lose any data... I checked for the Windows disk and I can se there's all my information there, so, I didn't lose anything.

Thanks.

---

I'm sorry I'm responding my own answer, but I need to solve this and I don't know how to alert someone, so I'm trying to reply my own answer. This is what I wrote in my last comment of the response that ***Avinash Raj*** gave me:

> Hi! I did it but the problem wasn't solved. Instead I've got more options in the boot menu, here's a photo: gyazo.com/1ba420cb16995132b530a1c75c30f598 . I also discovered how to enter windows: I changed the boot order to windows at first, so my PC loads my Windows instead of ubuntu, but what I want is a dual-boot selector like this: pureinfotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/… but with the two options (windows 8 and ubuntu). Is that possible? Thanks.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: disable secure boot in BIOS/UEFI. It is designed to only let microsoft signed code boot. You installed a linux bootloader, so you need to disable secure boot to be able to boot from grub.

Answer (score 1):

Change `UEFI mode` to `Legacy mode` in bios.And then,

Boot the windows installation disk,click on Windows recovery option and then select `command prompt`.Run the following commands in that command prompt,

```
bootrec.exe /FixMbr
bootrec.exe /FixBoot
bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd
```

Then remove the installation media,and change the boot-order to HDD.

OR

Download [`boot-repair`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) live disk.Make a bootable boot-repair live usb,change the boot-order in bios to usb.Once the live disk was boot up click on the option `Recommende Repair`.It will reinstall your grub.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But only a question: with this, would I lose any data from Windows?

Comment: you won't loose any data from your windows partition.I am sure about that.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but one other question: in the page you gave me, it says that I can boot Ubuntu from a USB and clicking "Try it" and then installing the boot-repair with the command line. Is it what I have to do? I'm trying to download the file but my internet speed it's not so good, so I have to wait a lot. Is it a good idea to do it from this way? Thanks, and sorry!

Comment: ok try that.Is there any problem post here,i will try to help you.

Comment: Hi! I did it but the problem wasn't solved. Instead I've got more options in the boot menu, here's a photo: http://gyazo.com/1ba420cb16995132b530a1c75c30f598 . I also discovered how to enter windows: I changed the boot order to windows at first, so my PC loads my Windows instead of ubuntu, but what I want is a dual-boot selector like this: http://pureinfotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/windows-8-dual-boot-choose-an-operating-system.png but with the two options (windows 8 and ubuntu). Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: did you able to boot into both ubuntu and windows?if no, boot ubuntu live-disk install gparted and upload its screenshot.